# Is App: /bin/rm a Friend or Foe in OSX?

Tags: osx, rm

Bitdefender Antivirus for Mac keeps notifying me that it has blocked App:/bin/rm with the following message:

> An app you previously chose to block attempted to access your protected files again. We blocked the app to prevent it from altering the content of your protected files.

Should I remove or freeze this App entirely or should I free it up to perform as needed by OSX?

If I need to remove it, please guide me with proper command sequence.

---

I blocked this awhile back on an alert from BitDefender, and it quietly continues to block it in the background. It was only after checking Bitdefender Notifications that I saw this oft repeated sequence. Having just gone into my BD settings to make adjustments, I now see `/bin/rm` and `/bin/rmdir` blocked in the App Access menu. I have unblocked them now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a friend. It is a very, very good friend. The type you invite into your house and let them keep a copy of your keys for you. The [`/bin/rm`](https://ss64.com/osx/rm.html) command is one of the basic tools of the operating system and the default command used when you want to delete a file. Removing it will most likely break your system since there are bound to be various programs that expect it to exist and use it<sup>1</sup>.

I am guessing (and I stress that this is a guess, I don't know how bitdefender works) that bitdefender blocked something, possibly malware, which was attempting to delete a file from your computer. Presumably, it tried to delete it using `/bin/rm`, and so bitdefender blocked `/bin/rm`.

However, completely disabling this essential utility is sort of like making rocks illegal because someone threw one at you once. The `rm` utility is a tool, one that can be used safely or dangerously, depending on how it is used.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I actually just tried this on an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. To my surprise, deleting `/bin/rm` didn't stop the machine from shutting down and rebooting normally. I can also still delete files from the GUI file manager. Nevertheless, deleting this sort of basic utility is not a good idea and I still expect it to cause problems at some point.</sub>

Comment: The vm still worked because most system utilities are written in a language like C. For which there are system calls available which can be used. The only things that would really break are shell scripts that call /bin/rm. And the days of init managers written in shell are long gone ;).

Comment: @Tim yes, but I still expected various things to be using higher level tools and not have their ow syscalls to the API. I'm pretty sure I would manage to break this if I used it for a few days as my regular OS.

Comment: that's probably true.

Answer (score -3):

I would definitely not think to remove /bin/rm, there is nothing wrong by removing this command breaking system, definitely beats the purpose of the command.

Comment: This initially reads like you would agree to remove `rm`. It's only on re-reading that it becomes apparent you are agreeing _not_ to block it